# Simple perceptron in Python

Tags: python, perceptron

I'm working on programming a very simple perceptron in Python without a threshold, and I'm using the sigmoid function but I need a clear guideline to follow, I have a confusion in how to construct the output.

```
Input = [(1,1,0), (0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,1)]
weights = [0,0,0]
output = sigmoid(input)
sigmoid = 1.0/(1.0 + exp(- Input)
sigmoid_derative = sigmoid * (1.0 - sigmoid)
```

I didn’t test the code in python , but it's just a mind storm as I learnt fro the lecture. But I'm not sure when I use the sigmoid_derative? 
I understand that the activation function will have 2 parts:

1. Adder:   `newInput= w1x1 + w2x2 + w3x3`
2. `sigmoid = 1.0/(1.0 + exp(- newInput)`

Then we will have the error function in order to know if the weights are accurate.

```
Error = 0.5 * (Target - Output)* (Target- Output)
if Error == 0 then Break;
else
Update weights.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That is not Python code at all. As I understand, its kind of a pseudo code.
2. Your question is more of a conceptual one, not related to Python or coding for that matter. So to give you a clear idea on that, you need to first compute the newInput the way you have done. The sigmoid function that is used as an activation function gives you the final output (Actual Output). This output is compared to the Target Output to get an error value that is used to update the weights. This iteration is repeated for all the inputs epoch by epoch until the error value goes below a suitable mark. Another possible way to terminating the algorithm is setting the maximum number of epochs allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope one of my article on Perceptron may help you to get a clear idea. My article is "An Intuitive Example of Artificial Neural Network (Perceptron) Detecting Cars / Pedestrians from a Self-driven Car". -- So, basically, this article was written for novices, just to get a better intuition. Here is the link:

https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI3fT.jpg)](https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10)